# Center hover of selected date (datepicker)

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I using jquery datepicker.

I need to center hover to selected date

Here is how it looks like now

[image]

Here is a class for cell

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default, .ui-button, html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:hover, html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:active {
  background: #fff;
  height: 32px;
  border:none;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

But it not centering

How I can solve it?

Comment: can you please add your code in jsFiddle?

Comment: `text-align: center;`?

Comment: Where is `display:flex` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add `text-align:center` in these below classes. you can also overwrite them with your parent class.

```
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
   text-align: center
}
```

and

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default, .ui-button, html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:hover, html .ui-button.ui-state-disabled:active {
    text-align: center
}
```

Check attached screenshot file

[image]

Comment: Thank's it's helped

Comment: @Balance If this answer helps accept this answer.